# Prevent Print Spooler from printing multiple copies

Tags: web-applications, printing, spooler

One of the requirements in my current project is to make sure that nobody prints multiple copies of the document once created. This is a intranet web-based application, using php-mysql and the clients would be in WinXP. Is there any way to prevent a printer from printing a multiple copies?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to tell us how the users print documents. Webbrowser or PDF? But anyway it will be very difficult or impossible to achieve